# sql - how to list properties not reserved within certain date-range?

Tags: sql, postgresql

reservations table:

```
  id  | fk_property_id |       arrival       |      departure      
------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------
 1    |            1   | 2013-01-11 14:00:00 | 2013-09-07 10:00:00
 2    |            1   | 2013-02-12 14:00:00 | 2013-09-07 10:00:00
 3    |            1   | 2013-03-29 14:00:00 | 2013-09-07 10:00:00
 4    |            2   | 2013-04-29 14:00:00 | 2013-09-07 10:00:00
 5    |            2   | 2013-05-29 14:00:00 | 2013-09-07 10:00:00
 6    |            3   | 2013-06-29 14:00:00 | 2013-09-07 10:00:00
```

properties table:

```
 id  |                         title                          
-----+--------------------------------------------------------
 1   | blah blah
 2   | blah blah
 3   | blah blah
 4   | blah blah
 5   | blah blah
 6   | blah blah
 7   | blah blah
 8   | blah blah
 9   | blah blah
 10  | blah blah
```

I need to list properties available for a certain date range.

For example user enters date-range:
arrival:   2013-06-29 14:00:00
departure: 2013-07-14 10:00:00

and I need to list all not-rented in that period properties. how do I do that?
I take it it should be a left join - but I can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the right condition:

```
select p.*
from properties p left outer join
     reservations r
     on p.id = r.fk_property_id and
        r.arrival < '2013-07-14 10:00:00' and
        r.departure > '2013-06-29 14:00:00'
where r.id is null
```

Here is the logic.  First, the time conditions need to go in the `on` clause.  In the `where` clause, they conflict with the `left outer join`.

The logic is that a room is available for *all* the days when there is no arrival before the later date and no departure after the first date.  This takes all the various overlap possibilities into account.

The final `where` just finds the properties that are available because there are no reservations.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways:

LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT p.id, p.title
FROM properties p 
LEFT JOIN reservations r 
on p.id = r.fk_property_id 
where arrival < '2013-06-29 14:00:00'
and departure > '2013-07-14 10:00:00'
and r.id is null
```

However, since you're essentially performing an anti-semijoin, `NOT EXISTS` could be better for you:

```
select p.id, p.title
from properties p 
where NOT EXISTS (
    select 1 
        from reservations r 
            where where arrival > '2013-06-29 14:00:00'
                 and departure < '2013-07-14 10:00:00'
                 and p.id = r.fk_property_id);
```

Comment: It seems to me that the 1-st example will only cover cases where user-entered range lays completely within db-reservation range. But what about cases when user entered range begins within reservation range but ends outside of it - so dates overlap but not inside each other fully?

Comment: whoops. i flipped the test

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use `IS NULL` with your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` table. Meaning that nothing was found in the reservations table for that specific property.

```
SELECT *
FROM properties LEFT OUTER JOIN reservations ON properties.id =     reservations.fk_property_id AND a
WHERE arrival > '2013-06-29 14:00:00'
AND departure < '2013-07-14 10:00:00'
AND reservations.arrival IS NULL
```

Comment: i'm not sure as to how postgres will handle the `IS NULL` filter along with the filter on the date for `arrival`. Otherwise looks good.